# Unable to access the service created after successful deployment in the wso2 BRS?

Tags: wso2

I am not able to access the service after successful creation in wso2 BRS. Mean while I have one more doubt like while creating the service through **wizard**, coming to operation the name space value is more confusing for me. I don't know how to specify those namesspaces and in examples it is just showing like **http://com.test/servicename** it is not working for me.And one more thing that I not able to access the endpoint created after service creation.By the way I am using Business Rules Server 2.1.0. Please suggest me the good solution to this problem.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We may solve this issue if you specify the correct namespace according to the way you build your java classes. 
Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS210/Creating+and+Deploying+the+Rule+Service for more details on creating rule service and deploying them. 
In general, you can get an idea about namespaces by referring:
1. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp
2. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/